# Oracle 11g Error: Ora-00942 on existing table

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper

When I run this query to see the tables available for user Scott in PL/SQL Developer, I get 11 tables including the table EMP.

```
Select Table_Name
From All_Tables
Where Owner = 'SCOTT';
```

But when i try to access table emp in PL/SQL Developer with a select all like this:

```
select * from emp;
```

I get an 0ra-00942 table or view doesn't exist error. However in SQL*PLUS within the same schema the same select statement is giving me contents of the table emp. What is causing this error in PL/SQL Developer?

Answer (score 2):

What user are you using to connect to the database when you are using PL/SQL Developer?  Assuming that you are using a user other than SCOTT, you probably need to use a fully qualified name

```
SELECT *
  FROM scott.emp
```

You could also create a synonym in whatever schema you are using

```
CREATE SYNONYM emp
   FOR scott.emp
```

and then use the synonym in your query

```
-- This resolves to the private synonym that you just created
SELECT *
  FROM emp
```

Comment: Thanks Justin.....I logged in as user Scott, but if I fully qualify the name as you pointed out (scott.emp) it works well.

Comment: @Victor - That strongly implies that you are not actually logged in as SCOTT.  The only way that you could be logged in as SCOTT and for the query to require a fully qualified schema name would be if you issued an `ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = some_other_schema` which seems highly unlikely.